# Update Paypal subscription to require default shipping address?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Using the Paypal API endpoint as described in the documentation here: [Paypal Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) I want to retroactively require a shipping address for an active subscription. Is there a way to have the API use the default address data of the customer as it would have been used during the checkout? I don't have any address data collected but maybe Paypal provides a solution like `shipping_address.default`

Answer (score 0):

No. Patch the subcription with the data obtained yourself, or have the customer re-subscribe again. PayPal won't manufacture data for you without a checkout.